# batch command explanation del %~dp0 + "test.txt"

Tags: batch-file

for test I've executed this bat file

```
del %~dp0 + "test.txt"
```

on my desktop which contained a test.txt file.
The test goal was to delete test.txt file.

After the execution, some files disappears. Why? What have I done??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I ask to explain me the batch instruction, only this.

Comment: _Which_ files disappear?

Comment: *What have I done?* You mean *other than foolishly running code I don't understand somewhere other than a safe temporary folder?* And *running destructive code without first testing it by either changing `del` to `echo` or at least adding `echo` in front of `del` to test safely?*

Comment: Exactly Mr @Ken, an error occurs in my mind in the middle of the night, just the necessary stupid action of the day.
Anyway, {.exe, .txt, folders} files. thanks for the help bosses.

Comment: OK. So I've told you what you need to do to figure it out. (Move your batch file to a temporary folder that doesn't have anything of value in it, and either change it to `echo ` or `echo del `, and run it to see what is displayed.) Have you done that yet? What do you see?

Comment: Just for clarity. Having 95K points on this site doesn't make you a super-mega-arrogant of all the times, and, above all, having 91 points doesn't make me a ignorant.

Comment: Wow. I try to help and get insulted. No problem. Won't waste any more of either my time or yours. Good luck.

Comment: now: there is a way to get my files back? del command is permanent like Shift+Del action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131848/discussion-between-ilsergente93-and-ken-white).

Comment: Seriously, I need to know what files disappear besides test.txt (and the script itself, I'm guessing). I can't answer the question otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @SomethingDark for your time. I've foolishly executed the command thinking the `+` operator was the concatenating operation. So I got the current dir of the bat file (desktop) and concatenated the "test.txt" file name even on the desktop. Certainly, some .exe file are disappeared. Echoing the command I can suppose I've deleted some files or folders with a specific pattern [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771049(v=ws.11).aspx).
I think to try restoring my files by some dedicated SW.
Do you have some advice for me?

Comment: Were any files _not_ deleted? My current guess is that you accidentally deleted the entire Desktop directory. Unfortunately, there is no way to recover files deleted with the `del` command without using uninstall software, as it bypasses the recycle bin.

Comment: A batch file containing the code `del %~dp0 + "test.txt"` does: 1. prompting you whether or not to delete everything in the directory containing the batch file itself (if you answered `y`, all files in that directory are deleted, including the batch file itself); 2. deleting a file called `+` in the current directory; 3. deleting the file `test.txt` in the current directory. The current directory is not necessarily the same as the parent directory of the batch file (although in your case it is, I think...)!

Comment: Thank you very much @aschipfl for your reply. It is what I needed. Yes, also the bat file is been deleted. But why are some folders not been deleted?
However, I'm trying to get the name of the files via Recuva. Thanks SomethingDark for your help.

Comment: `del` doesn't delete folders

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> A batch file containing the code del %~dp0 + "test.txt" does: 1. prompting you whether or not to delete everything in the directory containing the batch file itself (if you answered y, all files in that directory are deleted, including the batch file itself); 2. deleting a file called + in the current directory; 3. deleting the file test.txt in the current directory. The current directory is not necessarily the same as the parent directory of the batch file (although in your case it is, I think...)!

Thank you aschipfl for the answer (as comment of question).